# Assembly: ROL instruction correct?

Tags: assembly, x86

Lets say I have the following value stored in AX: 1000100001001 and in CL I have the value of 1.

When I perform the ROL AX, CL instruction, my SW tells me that the content of AX is now 10001000010010.

Shouldn't however the correct answer be 00010000100101? (I ROL all the bits to the left thus the MSB comes up as LSB on the right?)

Comment: Yes, MSB comes up as LSB. **But** you forgot to pad your value to 16 bits, you really have `0001 0001 0000 1001` in `AX` so yeah a `0` MSB comes back as a `0` LSB ;) Maybe you confused MSB with the most significant set bit, while MSB is just the most significant bit (bit #15 in this case), no matter if it's set or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your debugger fooled you by leaving out the leading zeros.

```
   1 0001 0000 1001
```

is actually

```
0001 0001 0000 1001
```

so yes, one left-rotation of that is

```
0010 0010 0001 0010
```

---

Note that `rol ax, cl` is pretty pointless if you know `cl` is 1.  `rol` by 1 has a special encoding, and there's a `rol reg, imm8` encoding you can use for other counts.

Comment: Oh yes! That was it. I'm so silly for not noticing. Thanks a lot everyone : 0

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting about the other bits that are set to zero (0) and you don't denote but are still there: `0001 0001 0000 1001` (16 bits). When you roll this, the answer is as given.